# Variables Undefined causing 'No item with the given ID could be found...'

Tags: arrays, loops, google-apps-script, directory

** Update: sample google sheet attached.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/196XWcynpe00rLpNRUR2wbq09KKLptEQfZAoMunKBMtw/edit#gid=1457586267

Goal is: 
teacher 1 folder -> period 1 day 1 folder -> student a folder 
Teacher 2 folder -> period 3 day 2 folder -> student a folder

I've been working on this code for weeks and it keeps giving me the same error.  I am trying to create two different folders for one student who has two different teachers.  The first is created perfectly and in the right place, but the second keeps crashing.  It says that my variables: resourcePeriodFolder2 and secondResourceTeacherName are undefined which causes the last variable: resourceFolderID2 to also be undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks so much!

```
function createOneFolder() {

var studentFolderList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Student Folders");
var teacherList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Teacher Name and Folder List");

// Open the sheet used
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Student Folders");

var rowId = 3;
var rowIdTeacher = teacherList.getLastRow();

var studentFolderListArray = studentFolderList.getRange("A2:J").getValues();
var teacherFolderListArray = teacherList.getRange("A2:L").getValues();

var teacherName = teacherList.getRange("A" + rowId).getValues();

// get teacher name from student list
var firstStudentPeriod = studentFolderList.getRange("E" + rowId).getValues();
var firstTeacherNameOnStudentList = studentFolderList.getRange("F" + rowId).getValues();

// run loop to get teacher name from list  
for (var k=1; k<=rowIdTeacher; k++) {
  if (firstTeacherNameOnStudentList == teacherFolderListArray[k][0]) {
    var firstResourceTeacherName = teacherFolderListArray[k][0];     
    var resourcePeriodFolder1 = teacherFolderListArray[k][7]; 
  }; 

break;
}

// create folder for one student.
var resourceFolder = sheet.getRange("C" + rowId).getValue() + ", " + sheet.getRange("B" + rowId).getValue() + " ..... grade " + sheet.getRange("D" + rowId).getValue(); 
var resourceFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(resourcePeriodFolder1).createFolder(resourceFolder).getId();
sheet.getRange("G" + rowId).setValue(resourceFolderID);   

// get second teacher name from student list
var secondTeacherNameOnStudentList = studentFolderList.getRange("I" + rowId).getValues();
var secondStudentPeriod = studentFolderList.getRange("H" + rowId).getValues();

for (var h=1; h<=rowIdTeacher; h++) {  // Problem somewhere in here.
  if (secondTeacherNameOnStudentList === teacherFolderListArray[h][0]) {
    Logger.log('It works!  Victory!!!!')
    var resourcePeriodFolder2 = teacherFolderListArray[h][9]; // *****undefined even though value is in spreadsheet*****
    var secondResourceTeacherName = teacherFolderListArray[h][0]; // ***undefined even though value is in spreadsheet***           
  };

break;   
}

// create a second resource folder for same student.

var resourceFolder2 = sheet.getRange("C" + rowId).getValue() + ", " + sheet.getRange("B" + rowId).getValue() + " ..... grade " + sheet.getRange("D" + rowId).getValue(); 
var resourceFolderID2 = DriveApp.getFolderById(resourcePeriodFolder2).createFolder(resourceFolder2).getId();  **//CRASHES HERE**
sheet.getRange("J" + rowId).setValue(resourceFolderID2);

}
```

Comment: Why the `break`? Why start your loops on javascript arrays at index 1?

Comment: I started at 1 because row 0 are column headers that don’t need to be looked at. Should I start the counter st 0?  Also I thought I should break the loop when a match is found   Is it redundant?

Comment: Look at where your break statement is

Comment: `var resourcePeriodFolder1 = teacherFolderListArray[k][7];` and `var resourcePeriodFolder2 = teacherFolderListArray[h][9];` I would have guessed that they would be on the same columns. But they're not.  And I think your break statements are in the wrong place or they're totally not required.

Comment: `var resourceFolder = sheet.getRange("C" + rowId).getValue() + ", " + sheet.getRange("B" + rowId).getValue() + " ..... grade " + sheet.getRange("D" + rowId).getValue();` and `var resourceFolder2 = sheet.getRange("C" + rowId).getValue() + ", " + sheet.getRange("B" + rowId).getValue() + " ..... grade " + sheet.getRange("D" + rowId).getValue(); ` are exactly the same since `rowId` has not changed.

Comment: You're going to have to single step through this script  check intermediate values to see where the problem is.  Without data it's tough find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an example spreadsheet would help, but shouldn't the reference be from the student to the cell that has the teacher name rather than creating a loop to find anything? 
You should already know where the data exists and could reference it directly, or is this spreadsheet constantly changing?

Comment: Hi, it will be changing as more students get added. And as more teachers get added.  I’m trying to get it to work with one student input using two different teachers.  Once I get that to work I can add more. Goal is: teacher 1, period 1 day 1 folder - student a folder Teacher 2, period 3 day 2 folder - student a folder